# How to split one large database table into multiple database tables

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I'm using `SQL server 2012` as `database servers`.
In my database i have a table with more then 2,00,00,000.
I want to split this table in multiple tables with 10,00,000 records in each table.
Can any one tell me is there any way in `Sql server 2012` to do this without using

> INSERT INTO table_name_2 SELECT * FROM table_name_1 WHERE condition_

or

> SELECT * INTO table_name_2 from table_name_1 WHERE condition_

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no special command to do this. Using a `SELECT * INTO...` is as succinct as it gets.

If table size is your worry then you could use a [table partition](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190787.aspx) or [view partition](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190019%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) as an alternative to splitting the table.